# JSON API questions. Included vs relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, json-api

I am reading [this](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-identifier-objects) before building an API endpoints. I read this quote about compound documents:

> To reduce the number of HTTP requests, servers MAY allow responses
>   that include related resources along with the requested primary
>   resources. Such responses are called "compound documents".

Here is a sample JSON response using the JSON API specification:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/articles/1"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      },
      "comments": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/comments",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/comments"
        },
        "data": [
          { "type": "comments", "id": "5" },
          { "type": "comments", "id": "12" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "9",
    "attributes": {
      "first-name": "Dan",
      "last-name": "Gebhardt",
      "twitter": "dgeb"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/people/9"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "5",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "First!"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "2" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/5"
    }
  }, {
    "type": "comments",
    "id": "12",
    "attributes": {
      "body": "I like XML better"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "9" }
      }
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://example.com/comments/12"
    }
  }]
}
```

So from what I can see, the relationships sections give basic/sparse information about the associations between the articles table and other tables. It looks like an article belongs_to an author and has_many comments.

What will the links be used for? Will the API have to use the link in order to receive more detailed JSON about the relationship? Doesn't this require an additional API call? Is this efficient?

The "included" section seems like it contains more detailed information about the relationships/associations?

Are both "included" and "relationships" necessary? What's the intuition behind needing both of these sections?

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that a `relationship` in a `resource` simply gives linkage data (that is basic data to uniquely identify the related `resource` – these data are the `id` and the `type`), in order to keep it to a minimum.

On the other hand, the `included` section is here in case you want to send along detailed information about some related `resources` (for instance to minimise the number of HTTP requests). Note that the `included` section is expected to contain *only* `resources` that are related to either a `primary resource` (i.e. within the `data` section), or an `included` resource (this constraint is called `full linkage` in the spec).

To put it simply, the `relationships` section of a `resource` tell you *which* `resources` are related to a given `resource`, and the `included` section tells you *what* those `resources` are.

As far as links are concerned, they may come in handy when you have a `has_many` relationship, for which the linkage data itself might contain several thousands of `id`/`type` records, thus making your response document quite big. In case those are not necessarily needed by your client when they request the base `resource`, you might decide to make them available through a `link`.

Comment: What's worst here... making multiple API calls that take time or a giant crammed up piece of JSON?

Comment: It really depends on your specific use case. When you query a resource, do you need some related resources? If so, include them, there's no point making several calls.

Comment: Note also that you can use pagination on relationships so that, for instance, if you were to make a Facebook clone, you would only return the last `n` posts along with a user profile, making the rest available via links.